# How To Search For Text In A Class Element With Javascript

Tags: javascript

I hope someone can help me. I am brand new to Javascript and am writing a script that executes different code depending on the error alert message being displayed in a banner box at login. There is a single banner element that gets displayed in all cases:

```
<div class="alert-body alert-body-visible" ng-class="{'alert-body-visible': animation, 'alert-green-visible': animation2, 'active' : animation2active}"><span ng-bind-html="alertMessage">The username or password is incorrect.</span></div>
```

but then, depending on the error, a customized error message is attached to it:

```
<span ng-bind-html="alertMessage">The username or password is incorrect.</span>
```

[Here's a photo of how this all looks in Chrome's Inspector:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lKR5M.png)

I need an IF statement to test whether the banner itself is present on the page, and if so, whether this specific message (or even one word from it because each message is unique) is present in that banner.

Detecting the banner was easy using this:

```
if(document.getElementsByClassName("alert-body alert-body-visible").length > 0)
```

But detecting the text on top of it, not so much.

I can't do a generic HTML search for all text on the page because there are overlapping words elsewhere that would make the results not unique, so I need some way of isolating this text as part of the alert banner element, if possible.

Any help with this that uses pure JS (I don't have or know how to work with external code) would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once you have the `div` element you need to get the `span` inside it. Once you have the `span` you can use `indexOf` on it's contents to "search" for whatever string you want.

**Explanation**

This: `!!alertBanner.length` converts the property to a boolean (0 to `false`, everything else to `true`). We do this because `indexOf` can return a 0 which will evaluate to false. So now in the assignment line `msgPos` will either contain a boolean `false` (if there is no `alertBanner`) or the character position the "search text" starts at (which could be 0).

So now our `if` checks to see if the position is not `false`, and if it's not, it checks to see if the position of the "search text" is not -1 (-1 means it was not found). If all that is true then we found what we are looking for.

```js
var alertBanner = document.getElementsByClassName("alert-body alert-body-visible");
var msgPos = !!alertBanner.length && alertBanner[0].getElementsByTagName('span')[0].innerHTML.indexOf('The username or password is incorrect.');

if(msgPos !== false && msgPos !== -1) {
  console.log('we have a login alert'); 
}
```

```css
.alert-body {
  background: lightblue;
  height: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="alert-body alert-body-visible" ng-class="{'alert-body-visible': animation, 'alert-green-visible': animation2, 'active' : animation2active}"><span ng-bind-html="alertMessage">The username or password is incorrect.</span></div>
```

Comment: I just tried it as written and it works great. But a couple of questions so I understand what's going on. First, it only seems to work on a single keyword. How can I search for the entire phrase? Second, can you please explain the reason for getting its length? Is that to ensure it is present at all?

Comment: I stand corrected. It does work on whole phrases. Thanks so much. Would really appreciate a brief explanation of: msgPos !== false && msgPos !== -1. Do these not serve the same purpose?

Comment: I added an explanation for you. If everything is clear and you understand and it works for you, would you upvote and accept the answer?

Comment: Thanks so much, and I did accept it, but I have one more question. Can you please show me how to reverse this logic, so that the IF statement applies only when the word is NOT found. In other words, when the banner is not showing at all or when the banner is showing, but not with that message. Thanks again.

Comment: And I see this a lot but have wondered what it does: adding the [0] after elements...

Comment: Because `getElementsByClassName` returns an array. So to get an actual element you have to get an index of the array. Hence the `[0]` means "get the 0 element of the array".

Comment: For your reverse condition change to `if(msgPos === false || msgPos === -1)`. Meaning: if it's `false` the banner is not showing and if it's -1 we didn't find the search text.